# cordova open external website in system browser instead in app

Tags: android, cordova

Cordova does't open external website in it app. When it launch it will open in system browser.
Here is my code

source: http://antonylees.blogspot.in/2013/02/launch-website-as-mobile-app-using.html

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script>

            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 

            function checkConnection() {
                var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
                var states = {};
                states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
                states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
                states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
                states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
                states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
                states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
                states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

                return networkState;
            }            

            function onDeviceReady() {
                var networkState = checkConnection();
                alert(networkState);
                if (networkState == Connection.NONE) {
                    navigator.notification.alert('This app requires an internet connection'); 
                } else {
                    window.location="http://www.google.co.in";
                }
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Dola</name>
    <description>
        Dola
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Dola Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <access origin="http://www.google.co.in" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>

</widget>
```

I search all around, all the documentation but still cant figure out the problem. Please help me out.

Comment: use inAppBrowser plugin to open the external website

Comment: @Rudrakshya, is your issue solved?

Comment: no still not solved. I add inAppbrowser. but it has url bar. I dont want that. I want my site in my app look like native.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way out is to edit your `src` tag in `config.xml` to point to your external website. This does not require the installation of InAppBrowser Plugin
content `src="http://example.com"`

Otherwise Install InAppBrowser and load your external website in the below fashion to avoid toolbar or zoom capabilities.

```
var ref = window.open('https://example.com/', '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no,zoom=no');
```

Comment: Edit the src tag in config.xml does not work for me. The website still opens in the system browser.